# Keep getting the error 'Internet Explorer has stopped working...' when scrolling down a page using Dragon voice recognition software

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer, dragon-naturally-speaking

My friend is using [Dragon Naturally Speaking 10](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/) on Windows Vista. Whenever she uses Dragon Naturally Speaking to scroll down a page in Internet Explorer 7, the browser gives this error:

[image]

Restarting doesn't help and she's up to date with Windows updates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do you have SP1 for Dragon Naturally Speaking?  It can be downloaded [here](http://knowledgebase.nuance.com/view.asp?60VQ=KFML).

Secondly, I agree with the suggestion of upgrading to IE8.

Next, I would next check for any add-ons in Internet Explorer that might be being misbehaving.  If any look Dragon-related or Nuance-related (the manufacturer's name) then disable them and resart IE.  If you can browse and scroll without problem, you'll have determined that it is not IE at fault, but the Dragon Naturally Speaking software itself.

In this case, the next step I would suggest would be to try a repair installation of the Dragon Naturally Speaking - unless everything works as you want without the add-on of course.

Go into the Control Panel, into Programs, look for the Dragon Naturally Speaking and click the Change or Repair button.  If you get another option to Repair, click it and let it run through the wizard.  Then restart.

Check in IE and re-enable the add-on, if required.

Failing this, I would [contact Nuance support](http://epay.scansoft.com/usa/default.asp?ContactProducts=naturallyspeaking), advising them of the troubleshooting steps that you have just tried.

Answer (score 0):

Could she try installing IE8 and see if that solves the problem?

I know it's not what you're asking for, but it might do the trick

Plus if it's a legal version of Dragon you should be eligible to get support, so just email them and ask them if it is a known bug

Comment: This was my first suggestion too, but unfortunately Dragon doesn't seem to work well with IE8

Comment: I looked for possible bugs, but I couldn't find anything.